# with draft.js is it possible to create a custom block span with classname

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wysiwyg, draftjs

I am using draft.js, and I have everything I need working except for one thing.

I want to be able to add a custom block option that will apply a span with a custom class (e.g. content) around the selected content in the editor.

Is this possible with draft-js custom blocks?

Any good examples out there? (didn't find anything when googling)

Comment: Do you want to wrap selected text to `span` with a custom class for applying custom styles to this class? If true, you can solve it without draft-js custom block.

Comment: @MikhailShabrikov Yes, this is my aim. If it can be done without a custom block, so much the better.

Comment: Is my solution fits for your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without wrapping text to the element with a custom class. You can style selected text with method `RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle`.  More details described [here](https://draftjs.org/docs/quickstart-rich-styling.html#content).
Look at this working example - https://jsfiddle.net/x2gsp6ju/2/

Define `customStyleMap` object. Keys of this object should be unique names of your custom styles and values - objects with appropriate styles.

```
const customStyleMap = {
  redBackground: {
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
  underlined: {
    textDecoration: 'underline',
    fontSize: 26
  },
};
```

Pass this object to `customStyleMap` property of `Editor` component:

```
<Editor
  placeholder="Type away :)"
  editorState={this.state.editorState}
  onChange={this._handleChange}
  customStyleMap={customStyleMap}
/>
```

In this example, I apply styles for selected text after click on appropriate buttons, I call `this.applyCustomSTyles` method and pass style-name as first argument. In this method I generate new `editorState` with `RichUtils.toggleInlineStyles`:

```
applyCustomStyles = (nameOfCustomStyle) => {
  this._handleChange(
    RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(
      this.state.editorState,
      nameOfCustomStyle
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: This doesn’t really answer the original question, which was about creating a new span and adding a class to it. In many cases this is much more efficient and easier to manage.